# Regex for 8 to 10 digits

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a simple regex exp that will validate a phone number. The number can be between 8 an 10 digits and there can be no other characters. Can someone help out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like ^[0-9]{8,10}$ does the trick.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

You could try this regex:

```
^[2-9]{2}\d{6,8}$
```

Comment: Phone numbers in many countries start with 0, not 2-9... Why so many upvotes?

Answer (score 4):

`\d{8,10}`: would be the simplest way

Answer (score 2):

Haven't checked it but i guess this will work [2-9][0-9]{7,9}

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
^[^01]\d{2}\d{6,8}$
```

Comment: No, first part (`[^01]`) matches any characters, for example letters